# Convert Finger Print image to comparable template

Tags: security, fingerprint

I have a finger print scanner which gives me only an image of finger-print(it's SDK doesn't provide any functionality for "converting" them into template and for comparing these templates).
My question is which approach should I use: look for an SDK which does provide functionality for converting and comparing finger-print images, or shpuld I write these algorithms on my own(which  seems hard and time consuming). If first method is preferred, What are open source/paid sdk's for that work? Can you give me some links

My device is Verifier 300 LC.

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: SourceAFIS [www.sourceafis.org] may be of help too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a free [NBIS Biometric image software](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nigos.cfm) and [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint) library based on it.

It seems that fingerprint image comparison can be easily developed, See [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/fprint@reactivated.net/msg01641.html)

There are commercial libraries available too:

- [VeriFinger SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html)
- [Griaule Fingerprint SDK](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/en-us/fingerprint_sdk)
- [Bio-Plugin SDK](http://www.m2sys.com/bioplugin.htm)

Answer (score 3):

There are many software available, You can start with **NBIS** which has many tools ex:minutiae extraction tools (**mindtct**),  Bitmap Image (JPG/PNG) to WSQ snd vice versa, etc., With NBIS.NET Some trouble is during image conversion 32bpp image to 16bppGrayScale or 8bppIndexed,

By learning from NBIS samples you can quickly learn and create your own proprietary FP matching algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for this fingerprint raw image conversion to WSQ standard in java and I found the below useful. Hope it helps.

http://jmrtd.org/index.shtml

and this https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD/tree/master/wsq_imageio

Comment: Have you used it somewhere? I need help in using it.

Comment: Yes I have used them and tried the conversions myself. It works fine with me.

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a working example for your case? It would be very useful

Answer (score -3):

I work for Lakota Software Solutions, Inc. and we have a commercial product available (free developer license) that will solve your issue.

Lakota's Image product is the only FBI certified WSQ encoder/decoder that is written in pure Java, and it is probably the fastest out there. We tested it and it was 5 times faster than the NIST WSQ encoder/decoder.

Converting between image formats is very simple and straightforward with Image.

```
byte[] rawBytes = ...
Image rawImage = ImageReader.read(rawBytes, ImageFormat.RAW);
Image wsqImage = rawImage.toWsqImage();
```

You can visit our website at http://www.lakotasoftware.com/products/image

If you are looking for a free version, you can look at Jnbis, which is a Java version of NBIS. https://github.com/kareez/jnbis.

Note that Jnbis has not certified by FBI to meet the WSQ quality requirements, which may or may not matter in your case. You can find the listing of certified WSQ algorithms at https://www.fbibiospecs.cjis.gov/WSQ/Implementations

Comment: Now that is a better answer compared to what your coworker https://stackoverflow.com/users/3649973/aaron-wilson put up yesterday ...